# (ANGULAR-12) Mat-paginator change page after condition

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-pagination

I'm looking for a way to change the page of the mat-paginator inside of my HTML.

When I edit a user, I want to stay on the same page as the mat-paginator.
So I store this information inside the currentPage variable.

But I want to say to angular, if this variable !null, go to this page of mat-paginator

```
<!-- Pagination -->
<mat-paginator  *ngIf="!currentPage" color="primary" [hidden]="dataSource.totalItems === 0" [length]="dataSource.totalItems"
    [pageSize]="dataSource.pageSize" [pageIndex]="dataSource.pageIndex - 1" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="onPaginateChange($event)" showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
```

thank you very much.

I tried to write two  but I can't re-render pagination without an event.

Comment: what kind of error occurs ? can you please give us code of block that demonstrate detail information

Comment: Hello, no error occurs i  am just looking for the way to do this.

Comment: as per my understanding you have mat-table with information of user & you trying to edit one of the from table & after save the record you want to stay on same page as currently user information have right?

Comment: @ParthM.Dave Exactly, the editing works, but i want to stay on the same page (of mat-paginator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.paginator.pageIndex = this.goTo - 1;
   const event: PageEvent = {
   length: this.paginator.length,
   pageIndex: this.paginator.pageIndex,
   pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize
};
this.paginator.page.next(event);
```

here `goTo` is variable which indicate on which page you want to go so after saving the information of user you need to put above code to navigate to page.

Comment: @Mehdy093 please mark as answer if works for you so it can be helpful to community.